# When my team shares their calendar with me, their event notifications get sent to my calendar?

Tags: events, calendar, shared

I am new with gsuite.

I manage a team and need access to their calendars. when I subscribe to their calendars, all of their events get sent to my phone calendar (50+) at a time. It then prompts me to accept or decline to the events that are NOT intended for me.

How do i fix this?

WHen i subscribe to calendars- their calendars get pushed to "my calendar" tab in google cal.
I read in help that their calendars should be pushed to "other calendar" tab?

Help :)

RC

I already tried to "hide" calendar in phone settings, the events continue to be sent to me.